# Consulta por generar un jquery para un hover en imágenes y texto

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Estoy realizando un trabajo [web](http://qkstudiodemo.com/pagofacil/v3/) y resulta que me están pidiendo para la siguiente sección que es la que dice viaja por argentina con las 4 imagenes full lo siguiente:

Cajas de fotos, el hover de la foto, debe afectar al titulo y cambiarlo de color (sacar el underline). 
Asimismo si selecciono el titulo debe hacer el mismo efecto de zoom en la imagen.

El problema es que no se como resolverlo si debería partir de algún script o si es por css, adjunto el codigo que realice de la seccion

```js
    $('.caja-beneficios').find('.img-1').hover( 
function(){ 
$(this).closest('.caja-beneficios').find('figcaption').find('a').addClass('onImgHover'); },
function() { $(this).closest('.caja-beneficios').find('figcaption').find('a').removeClass('onImgHover'); } ) 

$('.caja-beneficios').find('figcaption').find('a').hover( function(){ 
$(this).closest('.caja-beneficios').find('.img-1').addClass('onTituloHover'); }, 
function() { $(this).closest('.caja-beneficios').find('.img-1').removeClass('onTituloHover'); } )
```

```css
.caja-beneficios:hover .img-1{
  transform:scale(1.2);
}

.uno:hover .img-2{
  transform:scale(1.2);
}
.dos:hover .img-2{
  transform:scale(1.2);
}
.caja-novedades-2:hover .img-3{
  transform:scale(1.2);
} 
 

img.onTituloHover {
 transform: scale(1.2);
}
a.onImgHover {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px!important;
  color: red!important
} 


#beneficios-novedades {
  height: 439px;
}

#beneficios-novedades .caja-beneficios {
  width: 50%;
  height: 439px;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#beneficios-novedades .caja-novedades {
  width: 25.6%;
  height: 439px;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#beneficios-novedades .caja-novedades-2 {
  width: 22%;
  height: 439px;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#beneficios-novedades .left .bg-foto-1 {
  right: 0;
  height: 439px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 51vw;
  z-index: 24;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#beneficios-novedades .right .bg-foto-2 {
  background-color: red;
  left: 0;
  height: 439px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 24;
}

#beneficios-novedades .right .bg-foto-3 {
  background-color: blue;
  left: 0;
  height: 439px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 40vw;
  z-index: 24;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}


/*-----------------------------------------------*/

#beneficios-novedades .caja-beneficios .beneficios {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 25px 0px;
}

#beneficios-novedades .caja-beneficios .beneficios span {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffd100;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#beneficios-novedades .caja-beneficios .beneficios a {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  width: 400px;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 353px;
  text-align: left;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 33px;
}


/*-------------------------------------------------------*/

#beneficios-novedades .caja-novedades .novedades {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 25px 18px;
}

#beneficios-novedades .caja-novedades .novedades span {
  left: 17px;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffd100;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 3px 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#beneficios-novedades .caja-novedades .novedades a {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 17px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 21px;
  width: 218px;
  top: 140px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#beneficios-novedades .caja-novedades .clientes span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 17px;
  top: 220px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffd100;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 3px 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#beneficios-novedades .caja-novedades .clientes a {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 17px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 21px;
  width: 238px;
  bottom: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#beneficios-novedades .caja-novedades-2 .beneficios-2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 31;
  padding: 25px 18px;
}

#beneficios-novedades .caja-novedades-2 .beneficios-2 span {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffd100;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#beneficios-novedades .caja-novedades-2 .beneficios-2 a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  width: 250px;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 363px;
  left: 28px;
}
figure.snip1281 {
  overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 441px;
}
figure.snip1281 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
figure.snip1281 img {
  opacity: 0.7;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
figure.snip1281:after {

  width: 0;
  height: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
figure.snip1281 a {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

figure.snip1281:hover img,
figure.snip1281.hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
figure.snip1281:hover:after,
figure.snip1281.hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

/*segunda columna*/

figure.snip1280 {
  color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
}
figure.snip1280 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
figure.snip1280 img {
  opacity: 0.7;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 100%;
}
figure.snip1280:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
figure.snip1280 a {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}


figure.snip1280:hover img,
figure.snip1280.hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
figure.snip1280:hover:after,
figure.snip1280.hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}


/*tercer columna*/

figure.snip1283 {
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-height: 439px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
}
figure.snip1283 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
figure.snip1283 img {
  opacity: 0.7;
  max-width: 100%;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  min-width: 455px;
}
figure.snip1283:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
figure.snip1283 figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 30px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
figure.snip1283 h2,
figure.snip1283 span {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
figure.snip1283 h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  top: 318px;
}
figure.snip1283 span {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffd100;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
figure.snip1283 a {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
figure.snip1283:hover img,
figure.snip1283.hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
figure.snip1283:hover:after,
figure.snip1283.hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section>
  <div class="container-fluid hidden-xs hidden-sm" style="padding: 0">
    <div class="container" id="beneficios-novedades">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- 1 COLUMNAS -->
        <div class=" caja-beneficios left">
          <div class="bg-foto-1">
            <div class="imagen-destacada">
              <figure class="snip1281 yellow">
                <img class="img-responsive img-1" src="http://qkstudiodemo.com/pagofacil/v3/images/imagen-beneficios.jpg">
              </figure>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div>
            <figcaption class="beneficios">
              <span>Beneficios</span>
              <a href="#">¡Viajá por Argentina junto a Pago Fácil!</a>
            </figcaption>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- 2 COLUMNAS -->
        <div class=" caja-novedades sin-padding right">
          <div class="bg-foto-2">
            <div class="imagen-destacada-medio">
<a href="" title="">
              <figure class="snip1280 red hover">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://qkstudiodemo.com/pagofacil/v3/images/imagen-novedades.jpg">
              </figure>
</a>
            </div>

            <div>
              <figcaption class="novedades">
                <span>NOVEDADES</span>
                <a href="#">¡Realizá operaciones desde tu celular!</a>
              </figcaption>
            </div>

            <div class="imagen-destacada-medio">
<a href="#">
              <figure class="snip1280 red hover">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://qkstudiodemo.com/pagofacil/v3/images/imagen-soy-cliente.jpg">
              </figure>
</a>
            </div>

            <div>
              <figcaption class="clientes">
                <span>SOY CLIENTE</span>
                <a href="#">¡Descuentos exclusivos!</a>
              </figcaption>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- 3 COLUMNAS -->
        <div class="caja-novedades-2 right">
          <div class="bg-foto-3">
            <div class="imagen-destacada">
              <figure class="snip1283 yellow">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://qkstudiodemo.com/pagofacil/v3/images/imagen-novedades-2.jpg">
              </figure>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div>
            <figcaption class="beneficios-2">
              <span>Beneficios</span>
              <a href="#">Pagá tu cuota de autoahorro Volskwagen</a>
            </figcaption>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Yo veo que aparece el underline y se realiza el zoom cuando pasas por las imágenes... ¿que problema tienes realmente?

Comment: Que cuando pasas el mouse encima de la tipografía tiene aplicarse el efecto que cuando pasas el mouse por la imagen y por otro lado cuando pasas el mouse por encima de la imagen la tipografía deberia hacer algún efecto de hover cambiando de color algo de eso. se comprende?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el caso que quieras hacer que se cambie el estilo de ambos al hacer `hover` en uno o en otro esto se resuelve con css y a quien debes aplicarle el `hover` es al contenedor de la imagen y del título. Por otro lado si lo que quieres es cambiar el estilo de un elemento al hacer `hover` en otro, esto es solo posible por medio de javascript (en este caso utilice jQuery), aquí te muestro ambas soluciones:

```js
// este código es para resolver el caso en que quieres cambiar un elemento al hacer hover en otro
$('.contenedor1').find('img').hover(
  function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.titulo').addClass('onImgHover');
  }, 
  function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.titulo').removeClass('onImgHover');
  }
)

$('.contenedor1').find('.titulo').hover(
  function(){
    $(this).parent().find('img').addClass('onTituloHover');
  }, 
  function() {
    $(this).parent().find('img').removeClass('onTituloHover');
  }
)
```

```css
.contenedor{
  position:relative;
}
.titulo{
  position:absolute;
  color:white;
  z-index:1;
}

.contenedor:hover img{
  transform:scale(1.2);
}

.contenedor:hover .titulo{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

img.onTituloHover {
 transform: scale(1.2);
}
.titulo.onImgHover {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Ejemplo al hacer "hover" sobre contenedor se cambia el estilo de ambos (solo css)
<div class="contenedor">
  <a class="titulo" >titulo de ejemplo</a>
  <img class="" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-JREhSKN8sMM/VmH2B-jmFXI/AAAAAAAAIzg/ScNtA185M88/s1600/02273%2Bpaisajes01.jpg" />
</div>

ejemplo al hacer "hover" sobre un elemento se cambia el otro (jQuery)
<div class="contenedor1">
  <a class="titulo" >titulo de ejemplo</a>
  <img class="" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-JREhSKN8sMM/VmH2B-jmFXI/AAAAAAAAIzg/ScNtA185M88/s1600/02273%2Bpaisajes01.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, Que cuando paso el mouse por arriba de la tipografía tiene aplicarse el efecto que cuando pasas el mouse por la imagen y por otro lado cuand pasas el mouse por la imagen la tipografia haga algun efecto de hover cambiando de color algo de eso. se comprende?

Comment: entonces lo que tu quieres es que cuando pases por uno de los dos afectas la otra sin afectar la por la que estas pasando?

Comment: Claro! vos viste que cuando pasas por encima de la tipografia el efecto de acercamiento no se aplica. Sino que se produce cuando estas encima de la imagen. Por otro lado me pide que cuando uno se encima sobre la imagen el texto haga algo no se! que cambie de color por ejemplo

Comment: pero no te piden que hagas ambos al mismo tiempo?

Comment: Si podria ser! La idea es esa que cuando te pongas encima del texto se aplique tanto el efecto que hace la imagen como tambien por ahi que tengo un hover de color. y Lo mismo para la imagen que cuando te encimes sobre la imagen se aplique ese zoom que tiene y que el texto cambie de color.

Comment: pero eso ya se está haciendo justo ahora

Comment: ahora la otra opción que mencionas de ponerse encima de uno y darle estilos a otro la mejor forma de hacerlo es por medio de javascript y agregando clases

Comment: Claro bueno la cuestión es que no se como podría resolverlo.

Comment: ahí edite mi respuesta agregando ambas soluciones, espero te sirvan

Comment: Buenísimo!!! eso es lo que quería que haga. Mucgas gracias

Comment: Hola @LPZadkiel te quería preguntar si esto mismo que me hiciste en ejemplo se logre aplicar a una sola imagen y no a dos por separada. Como seria?

Comment: todo depende del selector, si el selector es el `id` se aplicará a un solo elemento, si el selector es un `class` se aplicará a todos los elementos con esa class entonces todo depende del selector si este apunta a uno o mas elementos, ya sea por `id`, `class`, `atribute`, `pseudo class`, `pseudo element`, etc. Todo corre por parte del selector

Comment: Claro! yo estoy acá aplicando al que dice nuevo programa http://181.170.97.168:8080/e-pagofacil/public/ pero cuando paso por encima de la imagen no me activa el color del hover del texto, que le puse un rojo

Comment: para esa pagina sería algo así como:


`$('.caja-novedades').find('img').hover(
  function(){
    $(this).closest('.caja-novedades').find('figcaption').find('a').addClass('onImgHover');
  }, 
  function() {
    $(this).closest('.caja-novedades').find('figcaption').find('a').removeClass('onImgHover');
  }
)

$('.caja-novedades').find('figcaption').find('a').hover(
  function(){
    $(this).closest('..caja-novedades').find('img').addClass('onTituloHover');
  }, 
  function() {
    $(this).closest('..caja-novedades').find('img').removeClass('onTituloHover');
  }
)`

Comment: cada una de tus imágenes tienen diferente estructura html y por lo que tendrás que hacer selectores para cada una

Comment: Si ahi actualice el post porque hay algo que no estoy entiendo que no resulta hacerlo andar. lo que agregue fue el script que me pasaste y los css.

Comment: en los del medio funciona bien pero en el de los laterales no.

Comment: Ya lo hice andar, tenia un problema de vinculo del script